# Unwanted tkinter trace event

Tags: python, tkinter, trace

I just discovered a nasty behavior in tkinter trace events.  When the user selects a character or characters to change, on the first keystroke two events occur: the first is the deleting of the selected characters and the second is the insertion of the first character typed by the user.   The problem arises on an Entry field that holds  a tk.IntVar as its 'textvariable".  When the content is a single digit, that first event leaves the field momentari]y empty; the trace event leads to a call on IntVar.get() and that in turn throws a Double conversion exception.  My workaround is to wrap the IntVar.get() call in a try-except but having all these try-except blocks uglifies my code.  Is there a cleaner way to handle this"? If so, either a link or an example would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a `StringVar` rather than an `Intvar`, and use the entry widget's built-in validation feature to prevent non-integer values from being entered. Then, do a final check for validity before using the value as an integer to handle the edge case of an empty value.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that when my priorities get back to normal.